# Is this a python decorators or python property?

Tags: python

I am a new python programmer, and I do not understand the mean of the code when reading the following code: `@predict_all.property('sequences')`.  I find that python decorator almost is like the `@decortor` style. So I am confused about this code`@predict_all.property('sequences')` when there is a dot that is `.` following the `@predict_all`. Is this a python decorator or a python property?

```
@recurrent(states=['states', 'cells'], outputs=['destination', 'states', 'cells'])
    def predict_all(self, **kwargs):
        pre_emb = tuple(self.pre_context_embedder.apply(**kwargs))

        itr_in = tensor.concatenate(pre_emb + self.rec_input(**kwargs), axis=1)
        itr = self.input_to_rec.apply(itr_in)
        itr = itr.repeat(4, axis=1)
        (next_states, next_cells) = self.rec.apply(itr, kwargs['states'], kwargs['cells'], mask=kwargs['latitude_mask'], iterate=False)

        post_emb = tuple(self.post_context_embedder.apply(**kwargs))
        rto = self.rec_to_output.apply(tensor.concatenate(post_emb + (next_states,), axis=1))

        rto = self.process_rto(rto)
        return (rto, next_states, next_cells)

    @predict_all.property('sequences')
    def predict_all_sequences(self):
        return self.sequences
```

**Supplementary information:**

The origin of the problem, why do I ask this question？

When I learn about the decorator, I find that most tutorials show that the decorator is simple like this style: `@timer`, that is `@` plus a functional name. And the property is like this style:`@property`, that is add `@property` before the method. So when I read the above code, I am confused what does this code `@predict_all.property('sequences')` meaning, I haven't seen this form of code before.So I am confused, is this code stand for a python decorator or a python property? I google it and find nothing about this style, that is `@` plus `.`. So I post this question on Stack Overflow and hope to get the useful answer or comment.

The example code of python decorator I have learned as follows:

```
def timer(func): 
    def deco(*args, **kwargs):  
        start_time = time.time()
        func(*args, **kwargs)   
        stop_time = time.time()
        print("the func run time  is %s" %(stop_time-start_time))
    return deco  
@timer 
def test1():
    time.sleep(1)
    print('in the test1')
```

Comment: Is that the complete code? can we put the output of the code as well?

Comment: The complete code is in this link [link] (https://github.com/adbrebs/taxi/blob/master/model/rnn.py) @ Reactive_learner

Comment: I do not understand why someone just downvotes this question but do not say any helpful answer or comment. So weird.

Comment: Why do you think it has to be one or the other? `predict_all.property` can be a function that *returns* a function that acts as a decorator. (We don't know what your `predict_all` is or where it comes from, so this is of course speculative).

Comment: Beyond that, "please explain this code" questions generally are frowned on here; they need to be *extremely* narrow and specific to be considered on-topic. This might well be on the acceptable side of that edge, but I can see reasonable views differing; one argument against is that it's not a standalone [mcve] -- we don't know which libraries are providing the code you're asking about, so the question is by nature a call for speculation. If you build something that stands on its own, including its `import`s and linking to libraries used, that's a lot cleaner.

Comment: Add some example of decorators I learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@` - applying decorator (syntactic sugar)

`.` - attribute access

`decorator` is something callable that returns something callable

`propertiy` is a specific kind of decorators, it is a class (descriptor) that returns object (descriptor object), in Python properties and descriptors are meant for attribute access control.

Now let's proceed to the question. `Is @predict_all.property('sequences') is a python decorator or a python property?` **It's decorator. It's not property.** `predict_all` returns object of `Application` class (https://github.com/mila-iqia/blocks/blob/master/blocks/bricks/base.py#L68). `Application` class has method named `property` which is a regular decorator used to get class attributes by specified name.

You may also consider the following example of using decorators (try it online https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user303_jaUkAvGSwi_4.py)

```
import time

def simple_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('i am simple decorator', func, args, kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@simple_decorator
def func_1(*args, **kwargs):
    print('i am func_1')

class DecoratorManager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.log = list()

    def not_that_simple_decorator(self, key):
        self.log.append((time.time(), key))
        def simple_decorator(func):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                print('i am simple decorator', func, args, kwargs)
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            return wrapper
        return simple_decorator

d_m = DecoratorManager()

@d_m.not_that_simple_decorator(key='pretty_key')
def func_2(*args, **kwargs):
    print('i am func_2')

def func_3(*args, **kwargs):
    print('i am func_3')

func_3 = d_m.not_that_simple_decorator(key='pretty_key')(func_3)

func_1(1, a=10)
func_2(2, b=20)
func_3(3, c=30)

print('decorator_manager_log:', d_m.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Charles Duffy said,  `predict_all.property` can be a function that returns a function that acts as a decorator.

You can take below's demo for your further understanding..

```py
class Predict(object):
    def property(self, condition):
        def wrapper(fn):
            def inner(*args, **kw):
                if condition == 'sequences':
                    print("sequences")
                else:
                    print("else")
                return fn(*args, **kw)
            return inner
        return wrapper

predict_all = Predict() 


@predict_all.property("sequences")
def foo():
    pass

foo()

# result -- sequences
```

hope it helped